# Decision boundary for KNN classifier

Tags: matlab, knn

I'm trying to plot the decision boundary for KNN classifier using `MATLAB`.

I have searched online and I found that `voronoi` diagrams are used to plot the decision boundary. But I have one question:

Suppose if I have 2 dimensional data like this:

```
class 1 : (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1)
class 2 : (-2,-2), (-2,2), (2,-2), (2,2)
```

How does the decision boundary change if we use L2 norm and L1 norm? More precisely, how to plot decision boundary for a KNN classifier using L1 norm and L2 norm? I'm even interested if we can do this using python. I'm a beginner to machine learning.

Comment: I would recommend using python for machine learning. There are many toolboxes available. The easiest (and good enough) solution for small applications is scikit-learn. There is a nearest neighbors algorithm in there which you can use. You should be able to find lots of documentation for it on the web

Comment: I have even looked up python documentation, but I did not find any material about the decision boundary using the norms.

Comment: Try here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html

Comment: I understand that this may be difficult if you are not fluent in python. But honestly, 90% of machine learning is python or R (where R is slowly being replaced by python). So if you plan to get deeper into the machine learning topic, it is worth taking the time to learn.

Comment: You are looking for a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).  Please consult the duplicate to help you plot this in MATLAB.